# Easy Way to Batch Edit in Angular UI Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Angular UI Grid currently allows for double-clicking on fields for editing, but you can only do this one at a time. Currently, I need a user to click on a button and then have all rows show the editable input fields. I was unable to find a solution online and am now posting a question here.

Anyone else have a current or easy hack for this before I have to start customizing the UI grid library (something I don't want to do yet)?

Thanks!

Comment: hi @justin are you complete grid inline batch edit in angularjs.if you complete give me some suggestion how to do now iam also facing that same issuse.

Answer (score 0):

It is plausible to do this by providing a custom cellTemplate where that template is the editableTemplate, or quite a bit of the editable template.  This would mean the edit widgets were shown at all times.

Having said this, the reason that ui-grid doesn't show all the widgets at once is performance.  When you have a table you tend to render a lot of DOM elements, and slower devices cant' reasonably render and scroll that many DOM elements.  You may also get issues with row virtualisation - you may end up with your editors pointing to the wrong elements in the data.

Is editOnFocus perhaps an option for you?

Answer (score -1):

So what i did is, i used an ng-show directive on cell template to show and hide text box by setting an attribute on entity object of ngRow. By default edit will be false. when you press edit button its is made as true and the text box will appear.

Please find the following plunker for your requirement

http://embed.plnkr.co/tdtCbI8pw6mdSjG4SflP/preview

Hope this helps!!!!!!